# Is there a way return just a sub-key and not the whole path in Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I've created a batch file that query's the data in saves it into a CSV file. 
The data I'm searching for is saved as a sub-key in the registry (the values inside the sub-key are irrelevant). 
I have the following query:

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config" >>%userprofile%\desktop\info.csv
```

And this is the result:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config\g1322222_127.0.0.1
```

But I just want to get the sub-key only: `g1322222_127.0.0.1` (which is under `\IPC Config`) and not the whole path, then save it in a new cell in the CSV file.

The reason being that we have to search a large number of computers for the sub key (it is a unique number in every PC and it is saved under the sub-key \IPC Config) and build a database in Excel, but the long path is crowding the CSV file.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It is easy... but not going to rewrite, so where is the code? _"I've created a batch file"_

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. I've already mentioned the `reg query` command and the output in my question. What more do you want to know?

Comment: Post the batch code you have written and I will modify it for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for just the subkey name, *and there's only one* *, then you could use this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "HKCU=&H80000001"
Set "RKEY=Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config"
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims={}" %%A In (
    'WMIC Class StdRegProv Call EnumKey "%HKCU%"^,"%RKEY%" 2^>Nul^|Find "sNames"'
) Do (Echo %%~A)>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\info.csv"
Pause
```

*If there were more than one subkey, (* or you wanted the single returned name inside doublequotes for your csv output), then you'd `) Do Echo %%A>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\info.csv"`*

---

**Edit**

If you want them each without quotes then you can use this modification:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "HKCU=&H80000001"
Set "RKEY=Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config"

For /F "Tokens=2 Delims={}" %%A In (
    'WMIC Class StdRegProv Call EnumKey "%HKCU%"^,"%RKEY%" 2^>Nul^|Find "sNames"'
) Do Set "_=%%A" & >>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\info.csv" Call Echo %%_:"=%%
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Worked like a charm! Just one more question. The second and third results were written in the csv file with double quotes but not the first one. Any chance I could remove them?

Comment: Read the bottom of my answer under the code, just change the last line to the one I've provided  there, _they should all be in doublequotes then_. The code is not designed to remove those quotes, you mentioned csv, which should really be in the format of doublequoted strings separated by commas. Additionally, my answer stated that it was for only a single subkey, in the format you needed, with more than one key, you'd need the doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the reg query output into a variable it is very easy strip off the last section using the `FOR` command. This is purely an example to show you how it can be done.

```
@echo off
set "var=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config\g1322222_127.0.0.1"
FOR %%G IN ("%var%") do set "newvar=%%~nxG"
```

And one other option using some trickery with the SET command using string substitution.

```
@echo off

set "var=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config\g1322222_127.0.0.1"
set "first=%var:\=" & set "last=%"
echo %last%
pause
```

This is my attempt at what I think you are trying to do.  I really don't like coding without more information.

```
 @echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Gizmo International\HCM\IPC Config"') DO (
    FOR %%H IN ("%%~G") DO >>info.csv echo %%~nxH
)
```

Comment: But this `g1322222_127.0.0.1` is a different number in every PC. That's what I'm trying to find. I also want to send it to the excel .csv file.

Comment: @amonraii I do not think you understand. We are showing you examples. Edit your question and post the code you wrote and we can better assist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what code you have written as you did not post it, but typically something like this should do.

```
@echo off
Set "string=some\path\info\string"
For %%a in (%string:\= %) do "set value=%%a"
Echo %value%
```

Where you will.replace the `set "string..` with the result of your `reg query` result.

Keep in mind that this will not allow for spaces in the value.